# Custom WHMCS login page

Tags: php, whmcs

I need to change the login page of WHMCS since the current one is a bit confusing with all those additional options which better be shown ofter user is logged in. I want to change the clientarea.php to just show a small dialogbox (would look cool after I add css and some jquery) on the whole page which asks the user to login.
I tried to find the tpl file specifically for  clientarea but could not find one. The clientarea.php file is encoded so can't really edit that.
Any guesses?

Answer (score 2):

You may use jQuery.append() and custom tags in .TPL files.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is editing login.tpl

and then simply having inside your dialogue box

```
 <form action="{$systemsslurl}dologin.php?goto=clientarea.php" method="post" name="frmlogin">
   <label>Email address</label>
   <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Your Email">
   <label>Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <button type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>
 <a href="/pwreset.php" >Forgotten your Password? Click Here</a>
```

The above form can be placed in any tpl file and will work  as expected
Note: the ?goto clause can be used to redirect the logged in user we use this to
navigate the user back to /cart.php?a=checkout when they are ready to buy.

Comment: Why this isn't the answer I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The client area is split up into several different template files. The files I think you should look at are header.tpl, login.tpl and footer.tpl. You should also look at the WHMCS documentation at http://docs.whmcs.com/Client_Area_Template_Files and http://docs.whmcs.com/Developer_Resources#Display_Customisation. WHMCS also offers support for these kinds of things as well.

Comment: But header.tpl and footer.tpl are common for all the pages. I just need the clientarea.php to show a login screen(without header and footer) if a user is not logged it and if he is logged in it should show the normal client area with the header and footers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the variables already set in Smarty.

The $loginpage variable returns true if login page is shown.

In header.tpl use the following code around the content you do not wish to show on the login page:

```
{if $loginpage ne "true"}
//nav menu etc
{/if}
```

You can also use this on your footer in the same way.  Then it's simply a case of modifying login.tpl to meet you needs.

If you want to show a different header and footer on the login page you could add an else statement like so:

```
{if $loginpage ne "true"}
//nav menu etc
{else}
//Different Content
{/if}
```

Sources: {debug} - This dumps all Smarty variables to a window.

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply create your own new custom page(php +Template File ) for your Login and You can validate the User Login using WHMCS API functions.

How to Create Custom Page : http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?20267-Creating-Custom-Pages

Login Validate API : http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Validate_Login

Comment: Can I create the custom login page in another site? when login, there use WHMCS's api, if success, then redirect to whmcs site?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.

As I have created ajax login to WHMCS Clientarea.

Create a file in root with name ajaxlogin.php and check email with encripted password,
after that set session uid and upw (Password hash).
thats all.

Answer (score 0):

1st you must know what Client Version you are using. 
To do this on vs 5.3.6 Go to Tab Setup click on General Settings and See Template.

This in source is located at /whmcs/templates

You can copy a directory and create your own template directory and it will show up in the General Settings.

Once you have done that, you will probably have to modify sever pages to get the desired effect.